# What to do if postgres socket deleted?

Tags: linux, postgresql, sockets, postgresql-9.3, filezilla

I was backing up a postgres 9.4 database using pg_dump. I dumped the database contents into the Linux `/tmp` directory. Unfortunately when I transferred the dump to a new server using filezilla, I accidentally deleted the socket file `/tmp/s.PGSQL.5432`. Now I can't even restart postgres or run this server. Does anyone know how to recover a database after loosing its socket file?

Comment: That sounds wrong. Unix sockets in the file system namespace are created with the `bind()` system call during process startup, so I'd check whether you accidentally also clobbered the permissions of `/tmp`, so the server cannot create a socket while running as the `postgres` user.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Is your PostgreSQL cluster still running (with no socket file) and you can't restart it? If so, could you stop the server with `pg_ctl -m fast stop` command? Could you post specific error message you get trying to restart?

Answer (score 1):

`kill` the database server to force a fast shutdown. Do *not* use `kill -KILL` (i.e. `-9`). The default signal `SIGTERM` is sufficient.

```
sudo pkill postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the database using pg_ctl:

```
pg_ctl stop -m fast -D /path/to/data/directory
```

Ideally you run this as the same user your database is using ('postgres' in most cases).

The "-m fast" option will terminate all open connections, and then shutdown the database. The default behavior of "pg_ctl stop" is to wait until all connections are closed - might be forever.